# Change elements upon button press?

Tags: php, html

I am getting started with HTML and PHP. Doing alright, I understand the syntax and everything. But... what I know is simply how to build page elements that may interact with other .php files in my site. But what if I want to interact with other elements in the same page?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
I got some text and a button. I want to press the button, and that will cause my text to become a textbox which I can edit, and afterwards press the button again to convert the textbox back to plain text.

That is what I don't quite get: interacting with other elements to change their attributes/values, seems to be little documentation about that, or I am looking in the wrong place. If that is the case, can someone point me to the correct learning source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need javascript for that.... There are loads of examples online and everywhere:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong place as you can't do that with PHP. Changing elements on the client side will involve JavaScript. There are a lot of ways to change elements with JS and to get a quick start I'd suggest you take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a JS library that will make it easy for you to access and change elements.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is client side interaction.  Javascript is the ticket for this and you'll have to include a  tag in the head of your html doc.

Look up javascript on [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com) and then learn [jQuery](http://jquery.com) which is a great implementation of key javascript principles with a lot of extra features like animation and client/server side interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You are moving into the realms of Dynamic HTML. The easiest way I have found to manipulate elements within an HTML page is to use [JQuery](http://www.jquery,com).

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a predominantly a server scripting language and has very little impact on browser-centric behavior. HTML is a markup language, but with few exceptions isn't dynamic. You want to look into content/browser scripting languages - depending on your medium, the two more popular for the time being are Javascript and Actionscript.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not allow you to change your HTML dynamically. As the other people mentioned, you need Javascript for that.

What you could do is reload the page on button click and change a session variable (for example) to decide wether the text is displayed as a textbox or just text.