# How to remove $_POST echo in textbox

Tags: php, post, input, echo, reset

How can i remove echo $_POST in my text once I pressed my reset button? here's my code, I think this is right but it doesn't work at all.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>"/>

<input type="reset" value="Clear" name="reset" />
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['reset'])){
    unset($_POST);
}
```

Website Reference: http://www.veryinternational.net/skunk5/page-4.php

Note: Try to fill up one of the required field(marked with red asterisk) and press the first button on left. Try to press the second button, the message on the textbox must be cleared.

Comment: FYI, you have a significant XSS vulnerability on your site.  You should be escaping all data from variables with `htmlspecialchars()` before using them in the context of HTML.  Not only does this keep you more secure, but it also avoids problems of a broken page when things like quote marks are posted from a form.

Comment: Whether the example is in your domain or not, make sure the PHP code is placed physically before the form output code, otherwise the POST payload will not be cleared until after it is used to populate the form field.

Comment: I would look into implementing some jquery. You could use a jquery function that changes the inner html of the div you choose. I would follow this to get started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796609/change-elements-upon-button-press It's really not hard to get going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two versions of reset here:

```
<input type="reset" value="リセット" name="reset" />
```

This resets the HTML form to its original state, before the user made any input. Meaning, the data you have already put there when generating the page will stay there. This is how the linked page does it.

```
<input type="submit" value="Clear" name="reset" />
```

This would submit the form in the currently filled state. But, as you made the button a submit button, you will have `["reset"]=> string(5) "Clear"` in your `$_POST` or `$_GET` data. I think this is more what you were looking for.

Comment: this one works, thanks a lot. is there any way if we press the reset button, the page should load faster rather than using the "submit" one?

Comment: The "reset" version does not send the form at all, it just sets it to its original state.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need php to reset a form you need javascript.

the built in HTML reset input type, resets the form to the original values (which is your PHP $_POST[email] value)

additionally, your test for $_POST['reset'] in PHP is never run because the HTML reset button does not submit...

in order to change the form field values to blanks you need to use a java script function.  Here is an example

```
<form name="data_entry" action="#">

Company Name: <input type="text" size="35" name="company_name">

Select Business Type: <input type="radio" name="business_category" value="1"> Manufacturer
<input type="radio" name="business_category" value="2"> Whole Sale Supplier
<input type="radio" name="business_category" value="3"> Retailer
<input type="radio" name="business_category" value="4"> Service Provider

Email Address: <input type="text" size="30" name="email">

Keep Information Private: <input type="checkbox" name="privacy">

<input type="button" name="reset_form" value="Reset Form" onclick="this.form.reset();">

<input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear Form" onclick="clearForm(this.form);">
</form>
```

Comment: http://www.javascript-coder.com/files/javascript-clear-form/javascript-reset-form-example.html

Comment: Or http://www.javascript-coder.com/files/javascript-clear-form/javascript-clear-form.js for the JS file for the script itself

Comment: Thanks for this but I tried this before, it doesnt work in other browser that's why I need to find other way for resetting the form